# like dislike code enter duplicate value in database

Tags: php

in my like dislike table i have 3 columns prod_id,user_id and like_dislike.i am inserting 0 for dislike and 1 for like.in below code i am inserting in like_dislike_tbl if there is no entry for particular prod_id and user_id with same like_dislike.it,s working if user change like to dislike or vice versa.but it will enter duplicate value if user like any prod_id that he all ready liked. here's my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('config.php');
$pid=$_REQUEST['prod_id'];
$uid=$_SESSION['uid'];
$act=$_REQUEST['act'];
if ($uid=='') {
header('location:login.php');
}
else
{
$like_sql=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_dislike_tbl WHERE 
prod_id='".$pid."' AND user_id='".$uid."' AND like_dislike=1");
$like_count=mysql_result($like_sql, 0);

$dislike_sql=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_dislike_tbl WHERE 
prod_id='".$pid."' AND user_id='".$uid."' AND like_dislike=0");
$dislike_count=mysql_result($like_sql, 0);
if($act == 'like'): //if the user click on "like"
    if($like_count == 1){
        header('location:'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
    if(($like_count == 0) && ($dislike_count == 0)){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO like_dislike_tbl(prod_id,user_id,like_dislike) 
    VALUES('".$pid."','".$uid."',1)");
    }
    if($dislike_count == 1){
        mysql_query('UPDATE like_dislike_tbl SET like_dislike = 1 WHERE 
    prod_id = "'.$pid.'" and user_id ="'.$uid.'"');
    }
    header('location:'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
endif;
if($act == 'dislike'): //if the user click on "dislike"
    if($dislike_count == 1){
        header('location:'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
    if(($like_count == 0) && ($dislike_count == 0)){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO like_dislike_tbl(prod_id,user_id,like_dislike) 
    VALUES('".$pid."','".$uid."',0)");
    }
    if($like_count == 1){
        mysql_query('UPDATE like_dislike_tbl SET like_dislike = 0 WHERE 
    prod_id = "'.$pid.'" and user_id ="'.$uid.'"');
    }
    header('location:'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
endif;
}
?>
```

give me your suggestions.thanx in advance.if u not understand my language.give comment whatever u not understanding.

my like_dislike_tbl is

```
------------------------------------------
|  prod_id  |  user_id  |  like_dislike  |    
------------------------------------------
|    8      |   20      |      0         |
------------------------------------------
|    9      |   20      |      0         |
------------------------------------------
|    8      |   20      |      0         |
------------------------------------------
|    9      |   20      |      0         |
------------------------------------------
|    10     |   20      |      1         |
------------------------------------------
|    10     |   20      |      1         |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?? I can't find any question

Comment: Add a unique key on `(prod_id, user_id)` so you can't have duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chane your code....

```
$dislike_count=mysql_result($like_sql, 0);
```

with this....

```
$dislike_count=mysql_result($dislike_sql, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table already has duplicates, `COUNT(*)` may return more than 1. So change

```
if (like_count == 1) {
```

to:

```
if (like_count >= 1) {
```

and similarly for `$dislike_count`.

BTW, you can get the like and dislike counts with a single query:

```
SELECT SUM(like_dislike = 1) AS like_count, SUM(like_dislike = 0) AS dislike_count
FROM like_dislike_tbl
WHERE prod_id = $pid AND user_id = $uid
```